# Why does the compiler report "operator<< and operator>> recursive on all control paths will cause stack overflow "?

Tags: c++, recursion, stack-overflow

```
#include <iostream>

class fraction {
    int n, d;
public:
    fraction(){}
    fraction(int n, int d) : n(n), d(d) {}
    int getter() { return n, d; }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, const fraction& a) {
        stream >> a;
        return stream;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const fraction& a) {
        stream << a;
        return stream;
    }

    friend fraction operator*(const fraction& a, const fraction& b) {
        int pN = a.n * b.n;
        int pD = b.n * b.d;
        return fraction(pN, pD);
    }   
};

int main()
{
    fraction f1;
    std::cout << "Enter fraction 1: ";
    std::cin >> f1;

    fraction f2;
    std::cout << "Enter fraction 2: ";
    std::cin >> f2;

    std::cout << f1 << " * " << f2 << " is " << f1 * f2 << '\n'; // note: The result of f1 * f2 is an r-value

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling error says:

```
operator<< and operator>> recursive on all paths, function will cause a stack overflow
```

I don't know what this means. What does it mean by recursive on all paths and which function is gonna cause a stack overflow?

Answer (score 3):

When you run:

```
stream >> a;
```

You are calling the same function you are running, ie `friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, const fraction& a)`.

So you will be calling yourself (*recursion*) again, and again, and again... without an end. This, in turn, means that the memory assigned to the *stack* will be exhausted at some point (because each *frame* takes some space) and it will cause a *stack overflow*.

Instead, you have to do something with the `fraction` argument `a`, most likely refer to `a.n` and `a.d`.

Comment: alright i have now set it to input and print a.n and a.d  but now the compiler gives out another error, binary ">>" no operator found which takes a left hand operand of type std::istream (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: @yoshikage22 I suggest you open a new question with the new code, that way it is easier to see the new code.

Comment: i fixed the other problem too but i didnt understand why did it work when i fixed it. so the operator>> functions fraction object parameter was constant and when it was constant it wouldnt let me write a.n and a.d, but when i removed the const from the fraction object paramter it let me write a.n and a.d and it worked perfectly. can you explain why when i removed the const the error in my previous comment got fixed?

Comment: nevermind i think i got it, when i made the fraction object parameter a const it didnt allow me to overwrite the previous numerator and denominator so i think that was the error. thanks